# IPV6 web server is unreachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ipv6

I deployed my code in AWS Elastic Beanstalk and setup a route53 dualstack cname for my load balancer.

[ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php)

I used this site to test my server. 
AAAA DNS record is good but the IPV6 web server is unreachable.

I've read several articles and answers and still don't have the idea how to solve my problem.

I have a guess that it is something to do with the nginx installed in amazon linux instance. But still no clue how to do it.

Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dualstack ELB hostnames do return an IPv6 address, but unless something has changed recently, ELBs don't yet answer on those addresses, because ELBs tied to VPCs don't yet support IPv6.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So I need to use other services to achieve an ipv6 web server?

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @ParthSolanki we used cloudfront. expensive, but it solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problably multiple issues:

Nginx config needs to be listening on both ipv4, ipv6

Something like this.

```
server {
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 80;
```

Also you need to make sure that your VPC has a IPV6 CIDR block. Which you can add from the VPC config page.

You will also need to update any ELB's that you might have to enable the routing and any subnets neets to support ::/0 ranges.